# How would I make an array of images appear on my react screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I am currently making a Mern application. I want to be able to print out an array of images to the screen. The images would come from a web url. Is that even possible? I have an array of images showing up on my mongo db collection, but there is nothing in it. It also doesn't show up on the screen after I input the data?
Has anyone got any ideas?
Thanks in advance!!!

Heres the code I have for the create !!!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import axios from 'axios';

export default class CreateNote extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        //binding "this" to all of those methods
        this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDuration = this.onChangeDuration.bind(this);
        this.onChangeImportance = this.onChangeImportance.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
        this.onChangeImage = this.onChangeImage.bind(this);<------binding this.onChangeImage
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            description: '',
            importance: '',
            duration: 0,
            images: [], <-----setting initial empty state
            date: new Date(),

        }
    }

    onChangeName(e) {
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.value
        });

    }

    onChangeDescription(e) {
        this.setState({
            description: e.target.value
        });

    }
    onChangeImportance(e) {
        this.setState({
            importance: e.target.value
        });

    }
    onChangeDuration(e) {
        this.setState({
            duration: e.target.value
        });

    }

    onChangeImage(e) {
        this.setState({
            images: e.target.value<---------------declaring onChange image
        });

    }
    onChangeDate(date) {
        this.setState({
            date: date
        });

    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const note = {
            name: this.state.name,
            description: this.state.description,
            importance: this.state.importance,
            duration: this.state.duration,
            images: [this.setState.images], <--------- set state
            date: this.state.date


        }

        console.log(note);
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/notes/add', note)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        window.location = '/notes';
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container2">
                <div className="txt">
                    <h2>Create a new Blog</h2>
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Blog Name</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required="true"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Choose a name for your new note"
                                value={this.state.name}
                                onChange={this.onChangeName}
                            >
                            </input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Blog Description</label>
                            <textarea type="text"
                                required="true"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Note description"
                                value={this.state.description}
                                onChange={this.onChangeDescription}
                            >
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Importance</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required="true"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Note importance"
                                value={this.state.importance}
                                onChange={this.onChangeImportance}
                            >
                            </input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Duration to read</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required="true"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Duration (in minutes)"
                                value={this.state.duration}
                                onChange={this.onChangeDuration}
                            >
                            </input>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>images: </label>
                            <input type="text"
                                required="true"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Image Url"
                                value={this.state.images} <------setting the state of image
                                onChange={this.onChangeImage}
                            >

                            </input>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Choose the date</label>

                            <div placeholder="Choose date">

                                <DatePicker
                                    selected={this.state.date}
                                    onChange={this.onChangeDate}>

                                </DatePicker>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Create note" className="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>


                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>


        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a fast view it looks `window.location = '/notes';` should be placed when resolving the submission request.
The `onSubmit` function would be something like:

```
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const note = {
        name: this.state.name,
        description: this.state.description,
        importance: this.state.importance,
        duration: this.state.duration,
        images: [this.setState.images], <--------- set state
        date: this.state.date


    }

    console.log(note);
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/notes/add', note)
        .then(res => {
             console.log(res.data));
             window.location = '/notes';
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

  }
```

EDIT: You should also consider adding a `catch` block in the axios post, you might be missing some request errors, it explains why mongo is not being updated